# Process.argv[] в JavaScript, нахождение общей подстроки

Tags: javascript, node.js, динамические-массивы

Помогите пожалуйста. Код ниже ищет *общую подстроку* для элементов, у меня вышло сделать это массивом. Собственно вопрос:
Необходимо использовать **process.argv[]**, никогда раньше с ним не работал и не выходит использовать его в этой программе. Нужно сделать так, чтобы функция принимала **сколько угодно** аргументов через **process.argv[]** и находила общую подстроку.

````
  var arr = arr1.concat().sort(),
    a1 = arr[0],
    a2 = arr[arr.length - 1],
    L = a1.length,
    i = 0;
  while (i < L && a1.charAt(i) === a2.charAt(i)) i++;
  return a1.substring(0, i);
}
console.log(
  longest_common_starting_substring(["ABCDR", "ABCDE", "ABEYF", "ABCDJOIJ", "ABCDDR",]));```

Вывод: AB
````

Answer (score 0):

**process.argv** - массив аргументов передаваемых в скрипт при запуске из консоли.

Достаточно написать **process.argv** в своем коде что бы к нему обратиться. Первым элементом будет **node**, вторым - название программы. То есть при передаче их в функцию надо отрезать первые 2 элемента **process.argv.slice(2)**
Пример:

```
if (process.argv.length < 3)
    console.log('');
else 
    console.log(myFunc(process.argv.slice(2)));
```

Пример команды для запуска из консоли:

```
C:\node myscript.js arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```